# How do I delete a comment associated with a post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I'm currently following along the basic Rails guide for creating a blog and I'm having trouble with deleting my `comments` associated with the post.

Here is my comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
 end

 def destroy
  @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
  @comment = @post.comments.find params[:id]
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
 end
end
```

In my views, the `destroy` action isn't firing at all.  So I can't even use the console as a tool to solve the problem.

Here is the views partial for `comments`:

```
 h2 Comments
 - @post.comments.each do |comment|
  p
   strong Commenter:
   = comment.commenter
  p
   strong Comment:
   = comment.body
  p = link_to "Delete Comment", [comment.post, comment],
  method: :delete,
  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

Generated html for the delete link:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/posts/9/comments/2"
rel="nofollow">Delete Comment</a>
```

Even my destroy action for posts is not making any requests, which makes me think the problem mightve been when I moved to partials.

Inside the console I can still delete a comment by finding the post by its `post_id`, then finding the comment associated with the post and destroying it. For some reason I can't figure out why the views link won't do anything.

Comment: I don't know much about the templating engine you are using, so I could be wrong, but should to the `link_to` look like this: `link_to "Delete Comment", post_comment_path [comment.post, comment],`. Also, are comments a nested resource of posts in your routes file?

Comment: @Max No, what is written now is fine, and your way is a syntax error.

Comment: Do you have a nested `resources :posts { resources :comments }` pair of routes?

Comment: @meager yeah my comments routes are nested within posts

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML for the delete link?

Comment: Just an idea: is your indentation exactly as above? the method seems to be indented at the same level as the p-tag... that *might* be bad.

Comment: Can you look at your rails log and watch as you click the delete-link and show us what gets printed? It's probably missing something simple and obvious, and the log will tell you what the dispatcher *thinks* is being asked-for.

Comment: @TarynEast simple and obvious is correct, it was the indentation formatting in slim.  Usually I am thrown a syntax error when my formatting is off, curious why it didn't happen with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, first of all be sure to place the correct indentation in your template, this may mess up things. Te last paragraph with the anchor link seems to be mistyped:

```
h2 Comments
- @post.comments.each do |comment|
  p
    strong Commenter:
    = comment.commenter
  p
    strong Comment:
    = comment.body
  p 
    = link_to "Delete Comment", [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

Then, you should look at the rails server logs to see what happens when you click on the link. If the HTML link looks fine, a call to the server *must* be there, with all the information you need to debug the call.

Answer (score 0):

1. first, you use Post.find(params[:id]) to retrieve the post you want to delete.
2. second you use @comment = @post.comments.where(post_id: @post.id) to retrieve all the comments that related to the post you deleted, where statment retrieve all results not only the first occurrence.
3. finally, you loop on these comments and destroy them.

   ```
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @comment = @post.comments.where(post_id: @post.id) 
   @comment.each do |comment|
       comment.destroy
   end
   ```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps.